# Politically correct term for someone who is Internet challenged?

Tags: single-word-requests, politeness, internet, euphemisms, political-correctness

What is the politically correct term for someone who is not very Internet savvy?

Comment: \*inserts joke about using Internet Explorer\*

Comment: "Luddite-American"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibilities include:

- She lives most of her life *offline*, only checking email once a month.
- He *isn't on the grid*, so the cell is the main way to contact.
- A proud *Luddite* when it comes to the Net, he doesn't own a computer and only surfs via the library.

Comment: All good possibilities, but +1 for Luddite. It may be more general and often used in a derogatory way, but many are reclaiming the term and its use seems to be [changing](http://www.onthemedia.org/yore/transcripts/transcripts_081101_luddite.html).

Comment: I would say 'Luddite' is a little strong, having an overtone of being actually anti-technology rather than simply unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 6):

With all due respect, "internet-challenged" is probably as benign as it's going to get.

Answer (score 6):

Most people would say "computer illiterate" as a softer way of saying NOOB but I am so tired of that expression so I voted up Chris' answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may also say in a more general sense:

> He/she is not a very technical person.

I have heard this used and I think it's specific enough to get the point across, but vague enough that it's not finger-pointing at a persons' deficiencies. It's not specific to the Internet, but these days enough people consider computers and the Internet synonymously that it's still effective.

Comment: He is not technically adept.

Comment: or any similar variation... "technically-minded", "technically-apt", etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the term "technophobe", but this would indicate someone who is *afraid* of technology more than someone who just isn't very good with it.

Comment: I don't take that word literally; usually when I hear that word it's meant as someone who isn't very good at technology.

Answer (score 2):

I hear the phrase "[digital divide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_divide)" on my local progressive radio station quite a lot. It describes a systemic, unfortunate lack of access to high tech without ascribing blame.

Answer (score 0):

"Illiterate," assuming it's clear lack of formal literacy if obviously not the case. Perhaps "deadwood" or "stuck in offline age..."

Answer (score 0):

I'd call such folk *internaughts*.