# Is there a word for someone who hates computers?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

If a *computerphile* loves computers then is there a word for someone who hates them? I've been trying to think how the prefix 'miso' might be used, e.g. misogynist vs philogynist, but haven't come up with anything.

"Phobia" means "fear" and implies an irrationality that I would like to avoid. The word I'm looking for would mean a strong but perfectly rational dislike of computers and/or computer culture.

I don't feel like a sample sentence is really helpful here but the tag says it's a requirement, so here you go:

> "How do you feel about computers?"
>   "I'm a staunch ______."

NB: The word I'm looking for would be similar to "misogynist" only directed toward computers, the Internet and/or Internet culture rather than women.

Comment: Of possible related interest: *[Is there a word for “people who are computer illiterate”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175546)* and *[Politically correct term for someone who is Internet challenged?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20565)*

Comment: @ab2 is that actually a word? Google didn't seem to think so. But that's definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research is shown ('computerphobe' should have been checked).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what research should have been shown? why should 'computerphobe' have been checked? Is it your opinion that the prefix 'miso' and the suffix 'phobe' are synonymous? If so I strongly disagree.

Comment: The suffix -phobe may connote fear / irrationality, but  denotes 'dislike of or prejudice against' in xenophobia, at least. cobaltduck does the work for you: computerphobia  n the fear or dislike of computers [Collins]. (and hence the related senses of computerphobe). You could have posted this and asked for a synonym without the connotations you don't want.

Comment: Alas, there is no good term.  When I was working in the biz I was known to occasionally, after an unusually frustrating interaction with one of the beasts, yell out "I hate computers!!".  "Computerphobe" or "Luddite" wouldn't fit, since I have no more fear of computers than the average guy, and I use them all the time.  I just don't like them very much!

Comment: *"The word I'm looking for would mean a strong but perfectly rational dislike of computers"* - It's not irrational to hate *using* computers, but I don't think a general hatred of computers can be "perfectly rational", any more than hating hammers or spoons would be. They're just tools.

Comment: Not exactly one word, but how about "retired computer programmer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the issues with hate is that its cause is often a lack: of knowledge, of understanding, of self-confidence.

With a close friend of mine, we use in French the neologism "**mal-computant**" or malcomputant, to describe somebody with very low ability or confidence in computers/internet/geek culture, and who often hates "them all", generally with little knowledge on the topic ("I hate Facebook, I never had an account").

The prefix [mal-](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mal-)  means  “bad,” “wrongful,” “ill” and is used in English for instance in malfunction,  malcontent. The French term [malvoyant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvoyant) means "lacking of the ability to see correctly". The English version points to "[Low vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_vision)" which redirects to [Visual Impairment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_impairment). Since the -phobia suffix did not match well, I thus propose [**computer-impaired**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2829/email-application-for-the-computer-impaired/2862).

In a comment,  technoluddite was proposed (from John ou Ned Ludd). However, the concept seems more akin to "[a technologist that longs for a simpler life](http://www.thetechnoluddite.com/2012/04/i-make-very-comfortable-living-using.html)". Luddism, by itself, sometimes refers to people that opposes to novel technologies, or criticizes them. Some talk about neo-luddism. The OP does not seem to convey such an active meaning.

Upon comments again, referring to geek culture, rare occurrences of [misogeekism or misonerdism](http://techrights.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/irc-log-techrights-16032013.html)  exist. However, it is not clear whether it is a fear of nerds or geeks, or a fear of the geek-culture.

---

For the record, my initial proposals were:

[**Cyberphobic**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyberphobic), from the second meaning  of [Cyberphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberphobia) (Wikipedia), since phobia may refer to hate or fear:

> Cyberphobia is a concept introduced in 1985, described as a specific
>   phobia expressed as "an irrational fear of or **aversion to computers**"
>   or more generally, a fear and/or inability to learn about new
>   technologies.

A related term is [logizomechanophobia](http://www.rantlifestyle.com/2015/06/02/15-bizarre-phobias-you-didnt-know-exsisted/):

> More than just sweating when needing to format an Excel spreadsheet,
>   people who have Logizomechanophobia won't go near anything digital.
>   Not computers, not ATM machines, not the kiosk at the airport - none
>   of it. It's often caused by a traumatic event caused by electronics.

Comment: The suffix "phobia" really only means "fear" though. In recent vernacular it has been used to mean "hate," e.g. "homophobia" or "islamophobia," but that's really an incorrect use I feel. Hate certainly grows out of fear, so an islamophobe may be likely to hate muslims as well as fear them, but the word itself doesn't mean that. Also, "phobia" implies an irrationality that I would like to avoid. The word I'm looking for would mean a strong but perfectly rational dislike of computers and computer culture.

Comment: A perfectly rational dislike. I will think about that

Comment: To me, "computer-impaired" implies that the person isn't capable of using and/or understanding computers and does not imply any particular feelings toward them. The word I'm looking for would be something like "misogynist" only directed towards computers, the Internet or perhaps Internet culture rather than women.

Comment: @Dave I did some update, based on your comments. Esp. explaining why I used impaired

Comment: @Dave 'The suffix "phobia" really only means "fear" though. In recent vernacular it has been used to mean "hate," e.g. "homophobia" or "islamophobia," but that's really an incorrect use I feel.' is the etymological fallacy. In English, usage rather than pedigree drives acceptability.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 18):

Possibly ***"luddite"*** which means someone who is opposed to all modern technology.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Luddite

> 1. one of a group of early 19th century English workmen destroying labor saving machinery as a protest;
> 2. broadly :  one who is opposed to especially technological change

Often it's used to describe people who aren't opposed to modern technology, but just don't understand it (and don't really want to bother learning how to).

Comment: One might even call them Neo-Luddites or technophobes, but of course it's much broader than just computers or even smartphones.

Comment: I thought about this word but I think it's too broad. I'm concerned specifically with computers and not technology and technological change as a whole. A luddite might easily hate nail guns, preferring hammers.

Comment: Technoluddite is a related and more specific term

Comment: @LaurentDuval Technoluddite may be the closest I'll get. The word seems a bit redundant to me (techno being short for technology, which luddite already implies) but it looks like, in the vernacular, it is used specifically in relation to computers and computer-related technology.
Thanks!

Comment: @Dave I have updated m'y answer following tour comments

Comment: This is the best choice IMO, but keep in mind that it's a word very few English speakers are familiar with.  At least that's the case in the United States.

Comment: @CharlesBurge it is definitely a BrEng word.  It is generally well understood in the UK.  I actually think "technophobe" is the best fit despite the OP's reservations about it.

Answer (score 3):

I thought we were going to have to coin this word, but it turns out it already exists at Merriam-Webster:

> [computerphobe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/computerphobe): a person who experiences anxiety about computers and especially about their use

And also at the Free Dictionary:

> [computerphobia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/computerphobia) (kəmˈpjuːtəˌfəʊbɪə) *n* the fear or dislike of computers

Comment: This is such a ridiculous word, mixing English and the Ancient Greek -phobia for fear. I'm aware that there was nothing close to anything technological back then, but I'm sure they could have come up with something better, or added a little something between computer- and -phobia

Comment: They did calculations. Seems like there would be a word there that could be used. "Phobia" really means fear I think and that's not what I'm going for. Hate, not fear, is what I'm looking for.

Comment: phobias are now 'dislikes'.  We're doomed.  I don't like beans... beanophobde!

Comment: @Dave absolutely, I was even looking for a word like that to go with phobia.

Comment: @user116032 and I'm a phobiaphobe, which is actually phobophobe.

Comment: @MorganFR haha :)

Comment: @MorganFR I don't like you, because I'm phobophobophobic.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion Wouldn't that be phobophobicphobic? As in the fear of someone afraid of fear, and not the fear of fear of fear. The latter includes the former, so I suppose it works too, but it is less precise.

Comment: @MorganFR _Computer_ is Latin, really, so in the end, it's just the good old technique of mixing Latin and Greek (_television_, anyone?). Still, it ain't purty.

Comment: __Technophobe__ is a currently popular version for this. Not exact but used in the same circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

In context, identifying oneself as a *dinosaur* would achieve your desired result. It might not be specific, but it suggests an intentional desire to stay away from technology--not necessarily out of fear but because you don't care to engage with it.

Comment: I feel like "dinosaur" is really a reference to being aged and the technology connotation is incidental. In conversation it could be used to get the point across but in a standalone sentence it would not. Saying simply "I'm a dinosaur" without any additional context would probably not convey to the reader that the speaker has a strong dislike for computers.

Answer (score 1):

The word [technophobe](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/technophobe) fits in terms of its usage. Strictly it should apply to all technology but these days people tend to use 'technology' to refer only to ICT,
 so technophobe fills the space in the OP's sample sentence nicely.

Comment: What's an icy tea?

Comment: @tchrist Either Information and Computer Technology or a long cold drink..

Answer (score 0):

**Techno-peasant**

When I worked in IT in London, we used to call them ‘techno-peasants’ alluding to the idea that they had ‘never come out of the fields, as far as computers are concerned’.

And - oh funny - it’s actually made it onto Wictionary!

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/technopeasant